# Android: Is it possible to force lower resolution for a phonegap application?

Tags: android, cordova, nexus-10

I have a single page phonegap app which makes use of CSS3 styles. Its performance is acceptable on all other devices except Nexus 10. I suspect that it might be related to the higher resolution that Nexus 10 uses.(2560 x 1600 pixels).

As per the benchmark tests (http://www.gsmarena.com/google_nexus_10-review-861p5.php), Nexus 10 falls behind other tablets. So to prove my theory I wanted to see if I can run my application on lower resolution mode on Nexus 10. Is it possible & how to do it? Can I use meta tag viewport with scaling 0.5? will that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Nexus 10 identifies itself uniquely you should be able to check for it with the [Device object](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html) in the PhoneGap API.

***update***

To get the performance change on the Nexus device scaling is not going to do it for you since the same number of pixels are still needing to be calculated - however the `target-densityDpi` viewport option will hopefully achieve what you require - see this SO Q/A [target-densityDpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595378/phonegap-target-densitydpi-on-viewport)

On the Nexus 10 the normal resolution is 300 dpi so you would want something like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densityDpi=150">`

Comment: I tried setting initial-scale to 0.5 but it doesn't seem to scale down the ui. I also edited config.xml as suggested in another question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579078/phonegap-scaling-down-a-webpage-with-viewport

Comment: On revisiting your question I discovered the target-densityDpi viewport option - see the revised answer

Comment: thanks for letting me know. However, sadly it doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing `android:anyDensity="false"` in the supports-screens section of the manifest file, if that helps..

Comment: I am using phonegap so I am not sure if it's possible to set any flag individually for screens. I will try to find it though.